# how to withdraw WBNB sent to a bsc deployed smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, etherscan, bscscan

i accidentally sent WBNB to a bsc smart contract address thinking it's the same thing, now if i go to etherscan and search for my contract address i can see the money stuck there but the contract address was deployed on bsc, Please how do i get it back

Comment: If the smart contract doesn't have a withdraw() function that allow you to retrieve your WBNB then you cannot get back your money.

Comment: it has a withdraw function but it doesn't have a withdraw token function

Comment: Give me the address of smart contract

Answer (score 0):

WBNB is a BEP20 token , so you can recover the token from your contract only if your contract has a function to transfer BEP20 token

Comment: WBNB is also ERC20 token too

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but a transaction sent WBNB back to the contract address.  The token doesn’t have a withdraw function but does have transfer functions.  I’ve been told a redeployment of the same contract with added functions could be used as a recovery contract but I really don’t know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You cannot redeploy a contract, unless it has that feature programmed in.